# can we add framework & images in Static Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, frameworks, static-libraries

i have made my custom `Static Library (.a)` successfully. i have tested it in demo and it is working fine. I have also added `get current location` & `check internet connectivity` `code` in my static library.

When i used my library to other `project` i have to add `CLocationManager.framework` & `SystemConfiguration.framwork` than it is working fine.

Now, i want to add some `images` and `both framework` in `static library` .
how can i make this possible .?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Were you able to add images to the Static library ?
if yes then Please share the solution, I need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm...I had a few problems time ago by trying to add an xcdatamodel in a static lib.

If adding images in 'copy phase' of you static lib target is not enough, I think you will have to create another target bundle in your static lib project and add the library itself in it. Or add the bundle alone in the main project in addition to your static lib. Which is a perfectly valid solution.

The framework has to be added in the including project.